# How does Teradata compile nonprintable characters ?

Tags: teradata

Teradata defines some special characters such as `0D0A'XC` for a new line etc. But where can I find the list for all such characters ? Where is it coming from ?

I need to know how these characters are getting translated. E.g. how to get a return carriage, etc

I tried to google this, but could not find such a list

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@Hillary  ,Teradata does not define any special characters; they are present in all the Databases.

Example:

```
CHR(9) = Tab key = '09'XC
CHR(10) = Enter key = '0A'XC
CHR(13) = Carriage Return = '0D'XC
```

Sometimes we need to add these to our data and sometime we need to remove them as per our requirement.
Usually they come when we do migration from other databases and when there is any change in the code pages between
two systems OR doing load to Teradata using some ETL tool OR loading file from windows to UNIX or vice versa.

If your source table contains Unicode character  and your target table field is defined as Latin character set you will get 
the issue of untranslatable characters.

Ex: Recently while doing a migration form oracle to Teradata  we found a weird issue like a char column is having
a data like ' G'(space and G) and we were thinking it as space but in fact it was CHR(0) .

Regarding translation , it depends do we need to remove them or replace them .  Mostly two UDFs are used for this (I guess they are available after TD 14)

`oreplace  : Select orepalce(col,CHR(0),'') from table` (what i did for my issue). `translate_chk  : TRANSLATE_CHK(‘abc’ USING UNICODE_TO_LATIN)`

At last there is no specific list, solve, add to your learning  and share as soon as you got some issue.

May be some Teradata expert  will give you more update... :)

Comment: `translate_chk` technically doesn't translate characters. It only tells whether a certain varchar string can be converted from one character set to another without generating error characters.
If you want to translate then use `translate( varchar_string USING UNICODE_TO LATIN)` where `UNICODE_TO_LATIN` can by any of the conversion strings supported by `translate()`.
If you want to force translation, even with non-translatable characters in input string, then use `translate(varchar_string USING UNICODE_TO_LATIN WITH ERROR)`. But bear in mind that error characters are tough to deal with.